# Must declare the scalar variable with SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following statement:

```
DECLARE @Nr_Karton int;

SELECT @Nr_Karton = ISNULL(MAX(Nr), 1000)  FROM W_Karton;

SET @Nr_Karton = @Nr_Karton + 1;

INSERT INTO W_Karton (Container_ID, Nr, Beschrieb, CreationDate, Location) 
  VALUES ('1', @Nr_Karton, '', getDate(), 'Bösingen');
```

But I get the error:

> [SQL] SELECT @Nr_Karton = ISNULL(MAX(Nr), 1000)  FROM W_Karton
>
> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@Nr_Karton".

How to get rid of the error?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What line does it occur on? As a side note, please don't re-invent identity columns!

Comment: @Bridge I edited to show full error. What do you mean about reiventing identity columns?

Comment: The code you posted parses with no error in SSMS 2008, is that really the code that gives the error? How are you executing it? Are you perhaps trying to execute it line by line instead of as a single batch? And as Bridge said, you should use an [`IDENTITY` column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775(v=sql.100).aspx) instead of generating ID values yourself.

Comment: @PandyLegend A column with Identity specification will automatically increment it's value as you insert new rows - that seems to be what you're trying to emulate by getting the highest value currently, adding one, and then adding that back to the table. Too bad it won't work if you've got concurrent sessions/multiple users etc. as you could get conflicts. I believe it's called `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL.

Comment: @brian, that is why he has `ISNULL(MAX(Nr), 1000)` in place. But the error says Variable not defined which is weird.

Comment: Can't reproduce - works just fine for me (SQL Server 2008 R2). Is this **really** exactly the script as you execute it?? You're not suppressing any `GO` delimiters or anything - are you??

Comment: @Kaf Good catch. It's actually the MAX function that prevents it from being null. If it was just ISNULL(Nr,1000) and the table was empty, it would be NULL on insert. Removed comment.

Comment: Are you running this in SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Try a different variable name say, `DECLARE @NextNr INT` ?

Comment: See comment below. This is the exact script! Not using SQL Fiddle (never heard of it!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some playing with this. The fictional schema I created was:

> CREATE TABLE W_Karton (Container_ID int, Nr int, Beschrieb varchar(1),
>   CreationDate datetime, Location varchar(10))

Whilst it parsed and ran fine on my local 2008R2 box, the same code did not work when pasted into a **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69234/12)**.

However, if you remove all the semi-colons apart from the last one as per this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69234/13)** you can see it seems to work fine!

I believe it shouldn't make any difference, but if you would rather it worked and don't care about the why, give it a try...

Comment: Nice catch. Wonder if the OP was using SQL Fiddle. Guess maybe it breaks it up into batches.

Comment: Same here - can't reproduce the problem, works just fine both on 2008 R2 and 2012.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, a bit of a weird one. Couldn't see anything more concrete - perhaps SQL Fiddle replaces the semi-colons with `GO` behind the scenes?

Comment: This worked. When I removed the semi-colons it was fine. The code was being run from a PHP script and I tested in Navicat - both were producing the same error. The reason that the code is incrementing the "Nr" field is because Identity is already on the ID field. This needs to be separate and isn't always going to correlate with the Nr field. If it is anything like MySQL, if you delete the last few rows from a table, the increment value will remain as 5 more than the (new, post-delete) last record.  Using this method would ensure that numbers in the Nr field are always consecutive.

Comment: There is probably a better way to do this but I didn't write it in the first place and am still getting my head around how the system should work. That coupled with my inexperience with MSSQL is making the job all the more interesting! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue.  It turns out it is due to ';' being selected as the "Query Terminator".  IN SQL Fiddle, this actually means "batch terminator".  There should be a drop-down button on the bottom right that has the text "[;]".  Click that and select "Keyword [GO]".